INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified
I’m encountering an issue during my Android project build in Android Studio. The build fails with the following error:
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.createAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.NodeUtils.processSingleNodeNamespace(NodeUtils.java:206)
    at ...

Here are the details of my environment:

Gradle Version: 8.7
JDK Version: JetBrains Runtime 17.0.11 - aarch64
Platform: macOS (Pro M3)

I’ve already tried the following without success:

Clean project and rebuild
Invalidate cache and restart
Fresh install of Android Studio
Download and use local Gradle installation

Could anyone suggest a solution or help identify the root cause? It seems related to XML resources, but I couldn’t find any obvious illegal characters.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

I am assuming that the stack trace is not telling you which specific file is at fault. You might first create a new scrap project in Android Studio and see if the problem occurs there -- if it does, then this would appear to be an environmental issue. If the scrap project builds fine, you may need to temporarily remove your XML resources, one at a time, until you find out which one has the flawed text.

None of what you've tried would address the problem of one of your XML files containing an illegal character.  I couldn't find any obvious illegal characters :  There are many possibilities that you'll likely not be able to spot.  Open each XML file with an XML editor or parse it with a good XML parser to find the culprit.  When you narrow it down to a single file, if you still aren't sure what's bad about it, post it here for further analysis/explanation.

I discovered that the issue was due to the default language of the device. It was causing an invalid character error during the build process. Changing the system language to English resolved the issue, and the build completed successfully.
